# Can I use every USB 3.0 A/A cable for Intel DCI debugging?

Tags: debugging, assembly, intel, uefi, usb-debugging

I successfully managed to enable DCI on my UEFI mainboard to enable debugging via a USB 3 DbC connection.
Now I need a USB 3 debug cable. I only can find one at DataPro via Google. It actually looks like a USB 3.0 Male to Male cable.

As I live in Germany it seems I cannot find a store offer such a cable and I wonder if I can use a simple USB 3.0 Type A to Type A cable (which I can get from Amazon) or if there is something special about those Debug cables I am not aware of.

Comment: Well, the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-usb-3-0-debug-cable-connection) also say: *This is an A-A crossover cable that has only the USB 3.0 lines and no Vbus.*  From the [DataPro](https://www.datapro.net/products/usb-3-0-super-speed-a-a-debugging-cable.html) page: *The USB 3.0 specification states that pin 1 (VBUS), 2 (D-), and 3 (D+) are not connected. This means that the cable is NOT backwards compatible with USB 2.0 devices.*  Something to check for anyway.

Comment: I checked multiple shops, and no one actually provides a datasheet or information about VBUS, so I guess safest way is to order then from DataPro

Comment: Sorry I can't offer more help.  I suppose any cable that claims to support 2.0 is bad, but other than that...  Did you look at [this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0032ANCC8/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i02?ie=UTF8&psc=1)?